# Powershell xml function error

Tags: xml, powershell

error from formatting xml in functions:

```
$newXml = @'
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
'@

+     $newXml =  <<<< @', is missing the terminator: '@.
```

Comment: You are going to have to give more context. There is nothing wrong with the string initialisation as posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two thing with `here` strings.  Make sure there is no whitespace after the `@'` and no whitespace before the `'@`.  That is, the closing terminator has to start in column 0.